# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to run an exe file on [msgraph-sdk-python-core](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core) from windows machine.
The exe is created from a simple python file by PyInstaller.

main.py

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient

def getGraphClient():

    client_secret_credential = ClientSecretCredential(
        tenant_id="tenant_id",
        client_id="client_id",
        client_secret="client_id")

    gRaphClient = GraphClient(credential=client_secret_credential)

    return gRaphClient

print(getGraphClient())
```

```
azure-core==1.26.1
azure-identity==1.12.0
certifi==2022.12.7
cffi==1.15.1
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
cryptography==38.0.4
idna==3.4
msal==1.20.0
msal-extensions==1.0.0
msgraph-core==0.2.2
portalocker==2.6.0
pycparser==2.21
pyinstall==0.1.4
PyJWT==2.6.0
pywin32==305
requests==2.28.1
six==1.16.0
typing_extensions==4.4.0
urllib3==1.26.13
```

In the development environment, it works fine, but when I convert it to Exe, I get the following error.

```
>main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
[19104] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I also tried --hidden-import 'azure' but it doesn't work.
'azure' has already been discontinued, do you know how to do this with Exe?

Comment: Microsoft Azure SDK for Python(pip install azure)
"Starting with v5.0.0, this package is deprecated. 
Please install the service specific packages prefixed by azure needed for your application."

I get an installation error with pip install azure.

Answer (score 7):

pip install didnt' work for me.

```
python --version
```

which showed Python 3.10.5

Did this:

```
pip3 install azure-storage-blob azure-identity
```

and was then able to use the imported azure functionality.

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
```

Comment: .\.venv\Scripts\pip3 install azure-storage-blob azure-identity
in my vs code folder

Answer (score 1):

instead, use this way to install:
python3 -m pip install <package_to_install>

Comment: you are saviour..

Answer (score 0):

I corrected it with `pip install azure-mgmt-compute azure-mgmt-storage azure-mgmt-resource`

See if it works for you guys

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading pyinstaller solved it.

```
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller
```